# Checking axioms on a specific problem of probability theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> **[K.L. Chung, Probability Exercises, Problem no. 5]** Suppose that on a shirt sale each customer can buy two shirts at ${$4}$ each, but the regular price is ${$5}$. A customer bought $4$ shirts ${S_1},...,{S_4}$. Write down a formula like Axiom $(ii)$. Forget about sales tax!

I know neither how to solve this problem nor can understand the whole thing. Please suggest some hints.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add what is axiom (ii)?

Comment: For any two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, the value of the function for their union $A+B$ is equal to the sum of its value for $A$ and its value for $B$. $P(A+B) = P(A)+P(B)$ provided $P(AB)=0$

Comment: This question is not well-formulated, in my opinion. Maybe in the book there is more context from which you can deduce what the author means?

Comment: Should I upload the pdf ??

Comment: @AnikBhowmick Sure.

Comment: http://93.174.95.29/_ads/7EAA01CC042744C0D3D4480B0EA64873